# TypeError: Improper input: N=5 must not exceed M=2

Tags: arrays, scipy, curve-fitting, shapes, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` with a custom fit function (roughly following [this](https://scipython.com/blog/non-linear-least-squares-fitting-of-a-two-dimensional-data/) tutorial):

```py
# Fit function
def fit_function(x, y, x0, y0, A, FWHM):
    return A*np.exp(1)*4*np.log(2)*((x+x0)**2 + (y+y0)**2)/FWHM**2*np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*((x+x0)**2 + (y+y0)**2)/FWHM**2)

# Open image file
img = Image.open('/home/user/image.tif')

# xdata
X, Y = img.size
xRange = np.arange(1, X+1)
yRange = np.arange(1, Y+1)
xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(xRange, yRange)
xyGrid = np.vstack((xGrid.ravel(), yGrid.ravel()))

# ydata
imgArray = np.array(img)
imgArrayFlat = imgArray.ravel()

# Fitting
params_opt, params_cov = curve_fit(fit_function, xyGrid, imgArrayFlat)
```

For some reason, Jupyter Notebook keeps throwing this error and I can't locate the problem in the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-eaa3ebdb6469> in <module>()
     17     imgArrayFlat = imgArray.ravel()    # Flatten 2D pixel data into 1D array for scipy.optimize.curve_fit
     18 
---> 19     params_opt, params_cov = curve_fit(doughnut, xyGrid, imgArrayFlat)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    749         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    750         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 751         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    752         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385     if n > m:
--> 386         raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
    387     if epsfcn is None:
    388         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

TypeError: Improper input: N=5 must not exceed M=2
```

I don't understand what `N` and `M` refer to, but I've read somewhere that this error gets thrown when there are fewer datapoints than parameters (underdetermined system) - which is *not* the case here as the image files have about 15 x 15 = 225 datapoints each. What might be causing the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to change the function to

```py
def fit_function(X, x0, y0, A, FWHM):
    x, y = X
    return A*np.exp(1)*4*np.log(2)*((x+x0)**2 + (y+y0)**2)/FWHM**2*np.exp(-4*np.log(2)*((x+x0)**2 + (y+y0)**2)/FWHM**2)
```

because only the first variable is treated as independent.

Currently you send an array inside `x` variable which is `np.vstack`-ed from two 1D arrays, hence the `M=2`: you have two datapoints. In the function all other arguments are treated as parameters to optimize (including `y`!), hence the `N=5`.

Comment: Heyyy, that seems to work! Could you please explain what happens? This looks like some kind of variable packing/unpacking, but instead of `*args` you're using `x, y = X`...it this equivalent to `(x, y) = X`?

Comment: @frankmertens It unpacks a np.array row-wise. To unpack column-wise you can use `x, y = X.T`. It is eqvivalent to `(x, y) = X`.

Comment: Ah, is this a specific NumPy syntax?

Comment: @frankmertens No. Try it with simple nested python lists.`a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, `c, d = a`. Of course the transpose method `T` won't work for python lists.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! By the way, is there an explanation why it's `c, d = a` and not `a = c, d`? AFAIK the `=` is a pointer between objects and `foo = bar` points `foo` to `bar`

Comment: @frankmertens Because you want to define two new variables `c` and `d` which refer to the rows of the original list. `a = c, d` makes no sense, `c` and `d` are not even defined. In mathematics that would make sense, but in Python if you want to create new things they must be on the left side of the `=` sign.