# how to pack my numpy variables and arrays when calling curve_fit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize, argument-unpacking

This is my standalone code to reproduce the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk(data):
    n = 20  # number of points
    time = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)

    guess_center_point = data.mean(1)
    guess_center_point = guess_center_point[np.newaxis, :].transpose()
    guess_a_phase = 0
    guess_b_phase = 0
    guess_a = 1
    guess_b = 1
    guess_a_axis_vector = np.array([[1], [0], [0]])
    guess_b_axis_vector = np.array([[0], [1], [0]])

    p0 = np.array([guess_center_point,
                   guess_a, guess_a_axis_vector, guess_a_phase,
                   guess_b, guess_b_axis_vector, guess_b_phase])

    def ellipse_func(t, center_point, a, a_axis_vector, a_phase, b, b_axis_vector, b_phase):
        return center_point + a * a_axis_vector * np.sin(t * a_phase) + b * b_axis_vector * np.sin(t + b_phase)

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(ellipse_func, time, data, p0=p0)
    center_point, a, a_axis_vector, a_phase, b, b_axis_vector, b_phase = popt

    print(str(a_axis_vector, b_axis_vector))
    shorter_vector = a_axis_vector
    if np.abs(a_axis_vector) > np.aps(b_axis_vector):
        shorter_vector = b_axis_vector
    return shorter_vector


def main():
    data = np.array([[-4.62767933, -4.6275775, -4.62735346, -4.62719652, -4.62711625, -4.62717975,
                      -4.62723845, -4.62722407, -4.62713901, -4.62708749, -4.62703238, -4.62689101,
                      -4.62687185, -4.62694013, -4.62701082, -4.62700483, -4.62697488, -4.62686825,
                      -4.62675683, -4.62675204],
                     [-1.58625998, -1.58625039, -1.58619648, -1.58617611, -1.58620606, -1.5861833,
                      -1.5861821, -1.58619169, -1.58615814, -1.58616893, -1.58613179, -1.58615934,
                      -1.58611262, -1.58610782, -1.58613179, -1.58614017, -1.58613059, -1.58612699,
                      -1.58607428, -1.58610183],
                     [-0.96714786, -0.96713827, -0.96715984, -0.96715145, -0.96716703, -0.96712869,
                      -0.96716104, -0.96713228, -0.96719698, -0.9671838, -0.96717062, -0.96717062,
                      -0.96715744, -0.96707717, -0.96709275, -0.96706519, -0.96715026, -0.96711791,
                      -0.96713588, -0.96714786]])

    print(str(find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk(data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That gives me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/lissajous-achse/ellipse_fit.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/lissajous-achse/ellipse_fit.py", line 49, in main
    print(str(find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk(data)))
  File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/lissajous-achse/ellipse_fit.py", line 25, in find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(ellipse_func, time, data, p0=p0)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\lissajous-achse\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 763, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\lissajous-achse\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 392, in leastsq
    raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
TypeError: Improper input: N=7 must not exceed M=3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is an adaption of the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716302/how-do-i-fit-a-sine-curve-to-my-data-with-pylab-and-numpy). The problem causing the error message is solved by simple packing of variables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432150/typeerror-improper-input-n-5-must-not-exceed-m-2).

Why does the problem not surface in the mentioned second answer? And how can I pack my variables, which consist of several 3d vectors and individual scalars, to solve this problem? How do i pass in my t, which is a constant and should not be optimized?

Comment: did i now answer my own question? should i start a new one for the new error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently python is quite smart regarding the length of the fields of the arguments, depending on the the initial guesses. So i could just pass in ONE variable, and split it up inside the function like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk(data):
    n = 20  # number of points
    guess_center_point = data.mean(1)
    guess_center_point = guess_center_point[np.newaxis, :].transpose()
    guess_a_phase = 0.0
    guess_b_phase = 0.0
    guess_a = 1.0
    guess_b = 1.0
    guess_a_axis_vector = np.array([[1.0], [0.0], [0.0]])
    guess_b_axis_vector = np.array([[0.0], [1.0], [0.0]])

    p0 = np.array([guess_center_point,
                   guess_a, guess_a_axis_vector, guess_a_phase,
                   guess_b, guess_b_axis_vector, guess_b_phase])

    def ellipse_func(x, data):
        center_point = x[0]
        a = x[1]
        a_axis_vector = x[2]
        a_phase = x[3]
        b = x[4]
        b_axis_vector = x[5]
        b_phase = x[6]
        t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
        error = center_point + a * a_axis_vector * np.sin(t * a_phase) + b * b_axis_vector * np.sin(t + b_phase) - data
        error_sum = np.sum(error**2)
        print(str(error_sum))
        return error_sum

    popt, pcov = minimize(ellipse_func, p0, args=(data))
    center_point, a, a_axis_vector, a_phase, b, b_axis_vector, b_phase = popt

    print(str(a_axis_vector, b_axis_vector))
    shorter_vector = a_axis_vector
    if np.abs(a_axis_vector) > np.aps(b_axis_vector):
        shorter_vector = b_axis_vector
    return shorter_vector


def main():
    data = np.array([[-4.62767933, -4.6275775, -4.62735346, -4.62719652, -4.62711625, -4.62717975,
                      -4.62723845, -4.62722407, -4.62713901, -4.62708749, -4.62703238, -4.62689101,
                      -4.62687185, -4.62694013, -4.62701082, -4.62700483, -4.62697488, -4.62686825,
                      -4.62675683, -4.62675204],
                     [-1.58625998, -1.58625039, -1.58619648, -1.58617611, -1.58620606, -1.5861833,
                      -1.5861821, -1.58619169, -1.58615814, -1.58616893, -1.58613179, -1.58615934,
                      -1.58611262, -1.58610782, -1.58613179, -1.58614017, -1.58613059, -1.58612699,
                      -1.58607428, -1.58610183],
                     [-0.96714786, -0.96713827, -0.96715984, -0.96715145, -0.96716703, -0.96712869,
                      -0.96716104, -0.96713228, -0.96719698, -0.9671838, -0.96717062, -0.96717062,
                      -0.96715744, -0.96707717, -0.96709275, -0.96706519, -0.96715026, -0.96711791,
                      -0.96713588, -0.96714786]])

    print(str(find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk(data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also i fixed some floating point vs integer errors in the vector for the initial values.

However now I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/lissajous-achse/ellipse_fit.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/lissajous-achse/ellipse_fit.py", line 58, in main
    print(str(find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk(data)))
  File "C:/Users/X/PycharmProjects/lissajous-achse/ellipse_fit.py", line 34, in find_vector_of_minor_axis_from_chunk
    popt, pcov = minimize(ellipse_func, p0, args=(data))
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\lissajous-achse\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 604, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\lissajous-achse\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 1063, in _minimize_bfgs
    if isinf(rhok):  # this is patch for numpy
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I guess that

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
> Use a.any() or a.all()

is some internal error, stemming from the internal decision matrix how to proceed. I don't know how I caused it and how to fix it. When i figure out how it is done properly, I will come back and edit this answer.